# Best way to back up entire system to upgrade to larger mSATA?

Tags: 12.04

I am a total Ubuntu noob.

I have a mini server set up nicely on my Intel NUC. All the settings are just right, with network mounts from my NAS etc. However, i used a 30Gb mSATA and am running out of room. I have bought a new 120Gb mSATA which i want to upgrade to.

Obviously i can't copy the files directly. I know there are several backup options, but can someone suggest what the best way (i.e. software) of doing this would be?

Presumably i will need to backup, partition and install a fresh system on the new mSATA, and then restore the backup?

Comment: What kind of storage do you have available for your backup?

Answer (score 0):

If you can hook both drives up to the same machine without mounting them you can use `gparted` to copy and expand the entire filesystem from the old disk onto the new.

Be cautious of the risks to your data during such an operation.

Comment: +azzid provides a good possible solution. In the same scenario, instead of using the Gnome Partition Editor, you could also use the `dd` command to completely replicate the first drive on the second. You would have to verify the compatibility of several parameters (e.g. things like sector sizes), but it should be doable. Then you could add a second partition with the remaining space, or possible expand the newly duplicated partition size with `gparted`.